# PHP Mailer Working on my server but not in client's SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, host

I am developing a form submit with PHPMailer the codes are perfectly running on my online server but its not working when I am using it in client's server, I was given the ftp to upload the files and I have uploaded all the required files to the server and double checked all the codes but still it's showing me this error `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.` I have found out this error after debugging. The client have provided this doc to follow:https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api

```
try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                      // Enable verbose debug output SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';                    
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   ='username';                     // SMTP email username
$mail->Password   = 'password';                               // SMTP email password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         
$mail->Port       = 587;
```

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that your server is not able to get connected

Comment: Check if server is avaiable or there is no firewall issue on it

Comment: There is nothing such that in it I have confirmed with client

Comment: Please check I have uploaded what error I have got

Comment: Is the 587 port open in the firewall/modem on both server and client sides?

Comment: Yes its opened on both the servers

Comment: I would also assume that this is a port issue. We have to take your word for it that the port is open for your client, we cannot check that in any way.

Comment: port is opened I did it I have followed this article https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-enable-port-587

Comment: OK, so you opened the port in your Windows client. Your PC probably connects to the internet through a modem. Let's assume the modem correctly forwards the port, although this is by no means certain, then you connect through your ISP. It's probably your ISP that blocks port 587. Ask them. Then ask again, because many employers of ISP's don't actually know this.

Comment: No i think you got me wrong i have done it through WHM, how it can be through my ISP, someone is filling the form from newzealand, some from uk

Comment: So the code is hosted by a webhosting service, on Windows. This wasn't clear from your question. If the code is running on a server the webhost is basically the ISP. My webhost certainly blocks port 587, I can only send mail after I've configured everything correctly so my webhoster lets mail through. Your cl;ient's webhost probably has something similar.

Comment: Try posting the whole code. Have you use and require the right statements at the top of the file ?

Answer (score 0):

This exact issue is covered [in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure).

You can't see what's going on because you didn't look at how the `SMTPDebug` options work, so you're only seeing the client side of the conversation. Set `SMTPDebug = 3` and you'll see much more useful info.

The problem you have is certificate verification failure. This is somewhat difficult to tell because you included debug output as an image - don't do that, use text. Given that this works on one server but not another, you can reasonably assume this is a client-side problem. Without the server side of the debug output we can't tell exactly what the issue is, but it's likely to be one of:

1. SMTP traffic is being redirected by a firewall to a different mail server, resulting in a certificate name mismatch.
2. The certificate has expired (though this is not likely as the other client works).
3. The client is trying to connect to the wrong server.
4. The client's CA certificate bundle is outdated, and it ca't verify the certificate.

This last option is the most likely, and will typically be fixed by ensuring you have all OS updates installed.